# C++ stl list two structures cross-reference

Tags: c++, list, stl, struct, cross-reference

I have such code with 2 structures:

```
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct Connection;
struct User;    

typedef list<Connection> Connections;
typedef list<User> Users;

struct User {
    Connections::iterator connection;
};

struct Connection {
    Users::iterator user;
};
```

But when I try to compile it, the compiler (C++ Builder XE) return me such error - "**Undefined structure 'Connection'**".

Can anyone help me with my problem?

@ereOn,
    struct Connection;
    struct User;
    struct Connection {
        Users::iterator user;
    };
    typedef list Connections;
    typedef list Users;

```
struct User {
    Connections::iterator connection;
};
```

**Undefined structure 'User'**

Comment: Where are you trying to use Connection? Some code from the file trying to use it would help.

Comment: Very strange, this compiled good at g++

Comment: Some actions appeared in my program, and I need get access to assosiated User struct, if I have Connection struct, and vice versa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using incomplete type as type argument to `std::list` which invokes undefined bevahior according to the C++ Standard.

§17​.4.3.6/2 says,

> In particular, the effects are **undefined** in the following cases:
>    — if **an incomplete type** (3.9) is **used as a template argument** when instantiating a template component.

So one solution would be using pointer of incomplete type.

```
struct Connection;
struct User;    

typedef list<Connection*> Connections; //modified line
typedef list<User*> Users;             //modified line

struct User {
    Connections::iterator connection;
};

struct Connection {
    Users::iterator user;
};
```

This will work because *pointer to an incomplete type* is a complete type, the compiler can know the size of *Connection** which is equal to `sizeof(Connection*)` even if `Connection` hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: The weird thing is, is the compiler allowed to raise an error instead of just compiling ? I mean, shouldn't undefined behavior only arise at runtime ?

Comment: @ereOn : Nopes! Undefined behaviour means **anything** can happen. That includes compilation error as well.

Comment: So, what solution can you offer?

Comment: @SteelRat: See the edit. I've suggested a solution. Let me know if it works for you. :-)

Comment: Thank, you. It works. But what is the difference in usage of struct as container element, and pointer to struct?

Comment: @SteelRat: Be aware that if you use a pointer, you now have to handle **deletion**. A nicer solution is to use a smart pointer (`shared_ptr` or similar) to do the job, so you don't have to care about that.

Comment: @SteelRat: Difference is that compiler can know the size of a pointer to an incomplete type, while it cannot know the size of an incomplete type. See the edit in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler tells you exactly what the problem is, that is `Connection` is **declared** but not **defined**.

You have to put the complete definition of your `Connection` type before your `typedef`.